# Keras model build for input image and output matrix

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, model

Hej guys,
I want to create model in tensorflow keras for images as input (width,height,3) and matrix as output (width, height).

Output matrix should contain values 0-1 or equivalent.
Example output for img 3x3x3 is matrix 3x3:

```
[[1,0,0],
[0,1,0],
[1,0,1]]
```

Of course i realized it wouldnt be exacly 1 and 0. But values close to that.

The question is:
Can u give me link to similar code or write example model layers and hint how to correctly compile and fit the model.

If it is important i am going to describe my data.
I have 4000 photos 2000x4000x3 which I want use to learn web. I also have arrays (2000x4000 which contains 0 and 1)

Comment: your input output shpae don't make much sense, clearly explain each dimension.

Comment: 3x3x3 means 3 colums, 3 rows, 3 channels. 3x3 means 3 columns and 3 rows. For flatten data. Img is vector 1x27 and output is 1x9